# How can I return a range of keys from a json object?

Tags: json, javascript-objects

I have json data structured in the following way from JsonPlaceholder API

```
'1': {
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "sunt aut facere repellat",
  "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit" 
}
```

I mapped the id as the key of the object and now want to return say objects '1' through '10' from the modified HTTP response shown above.

I tried using lodash `_.pick()`:

```
_pick(object, ['1', '10']);
```

but that only returns object '1' and '10' instead of '1' through '10'

All help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered just putting them in an array and then filtering it?

```js
let data = [
  { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 11 }
];

let filtered = data.filter(e => { return e.id >= 1 && e.id <= 10 });

console.dir(data);
console.dir(filtered);
```

if you can't and are stuck with them in a JSON object, maybe something like this that extracts the values first:

```js
let json = {
  '1': {
       "userId": 1,
       "id": 1,
       "title": "sunt aut facere repellat",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit" 
      },
  '10': {
       "userId": 10,
       "id": 10,
       "title": "sunt aut facere repellat",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit" 
      },
  '11': {
       "userId": 11,
       "id": 11,
       "title": "sunt aut facere repellat",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit" 
      }
};

var filtered = 
  Object
    .keys(json).map(key => json[key])
    .filter(val => val.id >= 1 && val.id <= 10);

console.dir(json);
console.dir(filtered);
```

Comment: Ok that sounds good but I inserted my modified response object into the data array just like this` data = [object]; `. No surprise I get an array with one object inside. But, how can I map my object's objects into the array so that it can appear like you say?

Comment: Thank you! This was the "key" to my solution! ..... Sorry for the pun, your awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using lodash why not just use range to create an array of integers and then map over that too convert them to strings.

```
_.pick(object, _.range(1,10).map(_.toString));
```